# Convert Date To Number With Sub-String Function SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in date datatype like column name `myDate`= 30/11/1998

I want to convert it to number datatype with only YYYYMM

how i can do it via oracle SQL ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Bad idea, probably!

Answer (score 1):

From date to number:

```
select  cast(to_char(myDate,'yyyymm') as int) 
from    mytab;
```

From char to number:

```
select  cast(to_char(to_date(myDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'yyyymm') as int) 
from    mytab;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query.

```
Select to_number(to_char(my_date,'YYYYMM')) 
from table;
```